# laravel - can't run phpunit - TestCase::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to run phpunit and get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp(): void in /Users/xxx/dev/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php on line 65
```

So I found the solution: add `:void` to `setUp()` and `tearDown` methods on tests.

So I changed the file inside laravel: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php`

```
public function setUp():void
{
  parent::setUp();
}

public function tearDown():void
{
  parent::tearDown();
}
```

It works, but the point is that I'm modifying a file which is inside `vendor` directory and it could be overwrited on composer commands.

How can I apply this solution without modifying a file inside `vendor` directory?

My composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.154",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.11",
        "crockett/csv-seeder": "^1.1",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "iugu/iugu": "^1.0",
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.35",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "malhal/laravel-geographical": "^1.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0",
        "tightenco/ziggy": "^0.6.7",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.2",
        "zizaco/entrust": "^1.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        },
        "allow-plugins": {
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: NEVER EVER edit a file or folder inside the `vendor` folder, NEVER. Now, show us your methods, you have something that is not following the interface...

Comment: What Laravel and PHPUnit version are you using? Share your `composer.json` please so we can see the original code

Comment: added composer.json file code

Comment: Well, you have `phpunit/phpunit: *` that is not good, you have to usually define a version, so it is more human readable... now you have to open `composer.lock` and look for `phpunit/phpunit` and see what version was downloaded... give us that number

Comment: found 3 occurences of phpunit in composer.lock file: "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8.36|~5.2"... "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0"... "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0|~6.0|~5.0|~4.8.35"....
I'm running phpunit 8 in bash

Comment: You did not exactly share what I wanted, you need to learn how to read composer. Still, I will answer your question

Comment: gonna try phpunit 7, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using PHPUnit 8, that is not compatible with Laravel 5.6, you must use PHPUnit 7, but not 8+. Why?

##### [PHPUnit TestCase.php](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/7d1ff0e8c6b35db78ff13e3e05517d7cbf7aa32e/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L475-L480)

```
/**
 * This method is called before each test.
 */
protected function setUp(): void
{
}
```

As you can see, it is defining `: void`, but [Laravel 5.6](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5ceadf91f13be89a3338c3d4166a4676272a23bf/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php#L60-L82) does not have it:

```
/**
 * Setup the test environment.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function setUp()
{
```

Because these files are `vendor` files, you MUST NOT edit them but install the correct versions of each one. Your fix is to change your `composer.json` from `"phpunit/phpunit": "*"` to `"phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"` as the official Laravel 5.6 composer.json has: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/0d5c1c81ff6faafbd8cc995aa3d0cd1b155df4c3/composer.json#L18.

You can see here, that [PHPUnit 7](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9467db479d1b0487c99733bb1e7944d32deded2c/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L404-L416) has a valid definition compared to Laravel 5.6 TestCase.php file:

```
/**
 * This method is called before each test.
 */
protected function setUp()/* The :void return type declaration that should be here would cause a BC issue */
{
}

/**
 * This method is called after each test.
 */
protected function tearDown()/* The :void return type declaration that should be here would cause a BC issue */
{
}
```